# Istio 1.1 Envoy access logs are not appearing

Tags: istio

This is a brand new Istio 1.1 installation on GKE.The cluster version is 1.10. Un fortunately Istio 1.1 has not been tested with 1.10, but my admin won't upgrade until June.

There is a feature in Istio 1.1 that does not exist in 1.0 that I need. And that is to configure a Gateway to look for TLS certs in kubernetes secrets.

However... I can't get any application to work because Envoy is not showing any access logs. How can I debug anything if I don't have the access logs?

I do see a whole lot of `deprecated` logs in the istio-proxy:

```
  3  Using deprecated option 'envoy.api.v2.Cluster.hosts'. This configuration will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md for details.
 92  Using deprecated option 'envoy.api.v2.listener.Filter.config'. This configuration will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md for details.
  1  Using deprecated option 'envoy.api.v2.Listener.use_original_dst'. This configuration will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md for details.
 44  Using deprecated option 'envoy.api.v2.route.Route.per_filter_config'. This configuration will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md for details.
 19  Using deprecated option 'envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpFilter.config'. This configuration will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md for details.
  1  Using deprecated option 'envoy.config.trace.v2.Tracing.Http.config'. This configuration will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md for details.
```

Does that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind... It looks like the new default for Istio 1.1 is that you must enable Envoy access logging...

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/12854

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [enable Envoy access logging](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/logs/access-log/) in Istio.